# How to inherit a partial class from user control to other one?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, user-controls, partial-classes

I've a problem with two user controls, first of all I've a user control named "Base" and I want to inherit it from another user control named "MyControl" but the "Base" control is a **partial** class and the user control "MyControl" just have a **public class**, so I use a partial class in "MyControl", and I use an ElementHost to show "MyControl" but I've the error **"Cannot implicity convert type *MyControl* to System.Windows.UIElement"**.
I try to add "MyControl" as a Child but it shows that error.
Help!

Edit:
The clases looks like:

```cs
public partial class Base : UserControl 
{
}  
public partial class MyControl : Base  
{  
}
```

And I want to do something like this:

```cs
public addControl() 
{  
    ElementHost _host = new ElementHost();  
    _host.Dock = Dockstyle.Fill;  
    _host.Child = _myControl;  
    panel.Control.Add(_host);
}
```

The error is at **_host.Child = _myControl;**. At this point the object _myControl is initialized.

Comment: Include code to illustrate this structure. You can strip out the insides, just show the class definitions and possibly constructors if you don't think anything else is related.

Comment: NOTE: Partial is used to define a single class across multiple files.  This is nothing to do with inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Does it look something like?

```
public partial class Base : UIElement
{
}

public class myControl : Base
{
}
```

I'm not sure what you mean by

> and I use an ElementHost

however, my guess is that you are trying to cast myControl as a ElementHost, but it isn't one.
Or myControl doesn't implement something that is required from UIElement.

Let me know if that helps.